# What type form of CDF fits this graph?

Tags: probability-distributions

[image: A CDF of a performance task]

Hi all, what kind of functional form of CDF do you think closely resembles this shape? Thanks!

Comment: Pick a software, say _Mathamtica_, or R and choose a family of likely families. Fit your data within each family using the method of maximum likelihood, and then compare values of maximal log-likelihoods and pick the family that yields the highest likelihood value. That would be your best bet.

Comment: What is the source of your data?

Comment: The source of my data is from an experiment I conducted. I was trying to build a simple theoretical model that could aproximate the outcomes from my experiment. I asked a question here [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484833/how-to-take-the-derivative-and-solve-this-equation) regarding that

Comment: Thanks Sasha, I unfortunately have never used such software, can you provide a link to a good guide for R? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the "score" seems to be a non-negative integer variable, and the CDF is S-shaped, a binomial distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) might have a good fit.

Another candidate (with just one free parameter) is the Poisson distribution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

In both cases, it should be straightforward to fit the distribution to your data using maximum likelihood estimation.